# US city, state and zip in XML, JSON or comma delimited?

Tags: arrays, state, city

I'm looking for any kind of flat file that contains every US city, state and zip code. I've searched high and low and can only find databases - which I'm fine using to create the flat file - but I thought I'd check here first.

If nobody else has a ready-made solution I'll parse through a database and post the flat file as the answer.

The reason I need this is for ajax auto-suggest. YQL and other free remote solutions are proving to be inconsistent and at worst, unreliable. I also do not want to make that many database calls.

Answer (score 12):

You could farm these JSON sets:

http://gomashup.com/json.php?fds=geo/usa/zipcode/state/IL&jsoncallback=?
http://gomashup.com/json.php?fds=geo/usa/zipcode/state/CA&jsoncallback=?

etc

Comment: links are not working ...

Answer (score 1):

Why not just load the data from a database into a javascript object in one ajax call and hook that into your autosuggest?

EDIT:  agreed with @elusive, 20,000+ municipalities is a LOT of data to load to each client

Comment: A LIMS system I'm configuring for work came with a ZIP table prepopulated with 70,000 entries, and I have no idea how (in)complete it is.

Comment: Please see my response to @elusive